How can I recover photos that won't export from a macOS photos library, can't be edited, and have no originals?
Hopefully this will serve as a more focused and generalisable version of this question and this question.

This isn't my system photos library so the photos aren't in iCloud.
About half the 12,620 photos in the library fail to export (Unknown error: -1), can't be edited (Cannot Start Editing: Photos can't load edits for this image.)  and have no corresponding file in the Originals subfolders within the .photoslibrary package.
The photos aren't thumbnails, or at least Get Info reports full resolutions.
Like other people who've asked for help for this problem, the problem photos seem to fit a date range. In my case this is from the start of 2011 to about mid-way through 2015.
The same issues occur with my oldest Time Machine backup of the library so restoring from Time Machine isn't an option.
I tend to always keep my media libraries consolidated and, if the file creation date is reliable, I created the library in 2021. So it's unlikely the problem photos were simply never copied to the library in the first place and subsequently lost their references.

I might be able to recover some or all of the originals from the people who took them. But, needless to say, I'm looking for a technical solution here.
Edit: Merging duplicates brought the total number of photos down to about 6,500, but unfortunately nearly 80% of those are "problem photos".

To clarify something, a full resolution photo can exist without an original file if it was ever re-rendered for an edit, etc. Then the image should exist in the Photos library just not in the originals folder.

@Ezekiel There's a Revert to Original command in the Image menu. So does the original get deleted on editing, with only the changes retained along with the new image?

It shouldn't be, in proper operation. But if an edit is made then a new version is created, so just being able to see the full resolution picture does not mean the original exists in the database if a malfunction occurs.

This question sounds like a good reason for periodically removing original photos from the .photoslibrary file/folder, and storing them somewhere else. IOW, you should Apple-proof your photographs!

@Seamus I think it's a bad idea to deliberately dig into the .photoslibrary package to remove originals, but a belt-and-braces approach would be to export photos periodically to a different backup location along with running regular Time Machine backups of the photos library.
